# Show the following projection map is finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let
$$P(X,Y)=T_0X^n+T_1X^{n-1}Y+\cdots+T_nY^n,$$
and let $V$ be the zero set in $\mathbb P^1\times (\mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus \{0\})$. Prove that the projection map $V\to \mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ is finite.

The map is certainly quasi-finite. To show it is finite, one may want to choose the affine open subsets $D(T_i)$ of $\mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. Hence we would like to show that $$R[X,Y]/(T_0X^n+T_1X^{n-1}Y+\cdots+T_nY^n)$$ is a finite $R$-algebra, where $$R=k\Big[\frac{T_0}{T_i},\frac{T_1}{T_i},\cdots,\frac{T_{i-1}}{T_i},\frac{T_{i+1}}{T_i},\cdots,\frac{T_n}{T_i}\Big].$$

Am I right? I don't know how to proceed. Thanks!

This is the example 8.39 of [the following note](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf).

Comment: There is something I don't get: does $T_0X^n+T_1X^{n-1}Y+\cdots+T_nY^n$ belong to $R[X,Y]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice (and useful) path to follow is to prove that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is finite if and only if it is quasi-finite and proper. If you do that, let $W$ be the scheme defined by $P(X,Y)=0$. Then $W\to\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ is proper (since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is complete) and thus $V\to\mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ is proper. Since you have shown this map is quasi-finite, you are done. In your case there are other ways of doing it too, but the general fact I mention is good to know.